# Problem connecting to Pi through SSH with Ethernet cable in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ssh

I want to connect through SSH my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ to my laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 just with an Ethernet cable without any internet connection.

1) Wi-Fi on for Pi and laptop [ok]

2) Wi-Fi off for Pi and laptop [problem]

---

**1) Wi-Fi on for Pi and laptop [ok]**

If I turn Wi-Fi on for my laptop and my Pi, I can get the IP address of the Pi with `hostname -I`, which returns two addresses for my Pi `169.254.176.100 192.168.178.80`, see picture below.

[image]

As far as I understand it, `192.168.178.80` is the IP address of the Pi due to Wi-Fi.

I can connect to `pi@192.168.178.80` through ssh from my laptop (user fernandez), see picture below

[image]

While Wi-Fi is on, `ip route` returns on my laptop

```
fernandez@emmabook5:~$ ip route
default via 192.168.178.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.178.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.77 metric 600 
fernandez@emmabook5:~$
```

and on the Pi

```
pi@emmapi1:~ $ ip route
default via 192.168.178.1 dev wlan0 src 192.168.178.80 metric 303 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.176.100 metric 202 
192.168.178.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.80 metric 303 
pi@emmapi1:~ $
```

---

**2) Wi-Fi off for Pi and laptop [problem]**

When I turn Wi-Fi off for the Pi and my laptop, `hostname -I` returns only `169.254.176.100` for the Pi, and nothing for my laptop (the address `192.168.178.77` was the one I had for my laptop while Wi-Fi was on), see picture below

[image]

I try to naively connect from my laptop to the Pi through SSH to `169.254.176.100` after connecting both with an Ethernet cable (the orange light for Ethernet connection of the Pi is on, so I assume, it is properly connected)

[image]

but it fails and I only get the error:

[image]

What does this mean or how can I connect through SSH to my Pi without internet connection only with an Ethernet cable?

For Wi-Fi off, `ip route` returns nothing on my laptop

```
fernandez@emmabook5:~$ ip route
fernandez@emmabook5:~$
```

and on the Pi

```
pi@emmapi1:~ $ ip route
default dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.176.100 metric 202 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.176.100 metric 202 
pi@emmapi1:~ $
```

Comment: @goldilocks I added the output of `ip route` for each scenario

Comment: Based on that, the problem is not the Pi; its routing is correct in both cases.  The problem is with the Ubuntu system. It is using the wrong interface for `169.254.0.0/16` in the first case and obviously has a problem in the second.  For that reason I am moving this to *Ask Ubuntu*.

Comment: Did you assign an IP address to each device?

Comment: @danzel no, sorry, I dont know how to do that, I just started with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if you have both your RPi and your Ubuntu machine on the same subnet. Set the IP address and subnet mask on your Ubuntu machine **manually** such that it's on the same subnet as your RPI, but with a different IP. Do this:

`pi@raspberrypi3b:~ $ ifconfig eth0
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.14  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::53b3:8c82:c0d6:57d5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:cd:2f:ff  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 143870  bytes 30387506 (28.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 65635  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 32375  bytes 4042276 (3.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0`

In this case you would **manually** set the IP address on your Ubuntu machine to `192.168.0.100` (for example), and set the subnet mask to `255.255.255.0`. Or, to put this in [CIDR notation](https://doc.m0n0.ch/quickstartpc/intro-CIDR.html): `192.168.1.100/24`. And the [Ubuntu docs already explain how to set your IP address **manually**](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html.en), so I'll not repeat that here. [(And here's the "GUI Approach" to manual network configuration)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9skwPdxXU0)

I've not done this in a while, but I think it will work. Let us know how you get on.